# VS code Live Server Web Extension server port 8080 problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vs code as a code editor for PHP. To view live time update I use vs code live server extension for chrome. Using Xampp(apache) for the PHP server. But suddenly I notice that some apps blocked my port 80 of windows 10 so I change the port for apache as 8080. Then my live server stopped working.

Can anyone tell me why this happened?

I want to add that if I change other ports like 8000 it works perfectly, what's wrong with 8080?  is there any other limited ports for the liver server?

Comment: This has nothing to do with vscode it’s a typical windows configuration. Often, 8080 is already taken, things like Skype, tomcat, a background service, db and many others default to it. It’s best to use your own. You can customize live server using their [settings](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/settings.md)

Answer (score 0):

It's highly possible that vscode live server use port 8080 internally

When Xampp is set to another port than 8080 and live server is started, use the following command in cmd to display a list of process using that port:

```
netstat -an | find /i "8080"
```

The PID of the process using that port is at the end of the line , then do the next command by replacing  with that number to find out which process opened it, you can also look in your task manager for that.

```
C:\  tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq <PID>"
```

Comment: netstat -an | find /i "8080"
 it doesn't show any pid value!!

Comment: Just FYI; live server defaults to 5500